# PHP array_multisort - how to keep the key values?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-multisort

How can I deep-sort a multi-dimension array and keep their keys?

```
$array = [
    '2' => [
        'title' => 'Flower',
        'order' => 3
    ],
    '3' => [
        'title' => 'Rock',
        'order' => 1
    ],
    '4' => [
        'title' => 'Grass',
        'order' => 2
    ]
];

foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $items[$key]  = $row['order'];
}

array_multisort($items, SORT_DESC, $array);

print_r($array);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Flower
            [order] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Grass
            [order] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Rock
            [order] => 1
        )

)
```

What I am after:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Flower
            [order] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => Grass
            [order] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Rock
            [order] => 1
        )

)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: check this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740747/array-multisort-with-maintaining-numeric-index-association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740747/array-multisort-with-maintaining-numeric-index-association)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

May be this is what are you looking for: [Online Example](https://3v4l.org/K5GhU)

Keep array keys, sort with the order column and combine them again.

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
array_multisort(
    array_column($array, 'order'), SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $array, $keys
);
$array = array_combine($keys, $array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

Comment: your solution is a workaround for php, I wonder if php 7.4 could improve this

Comment: This worked with very old version like PHP 5.2, where anonymous function is not available for using uasort.

Answer (score 14):

You can try [uasort](http://php.net/uasort):

```
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) { return $b['order'] - $a['order']; });
```

Your code:

```
<?php

$array = [
    '2' => [
        'title' => 'Flower',
        'order' => 3
    ],
    '3' => [
        'title' => 'Rock',
        'order' => 1
    ],
    '4' => [
        'title' => 'Grass',
        'order' => 2
    ]
];

uasort($array, function ($a, $b) { return $b['order'] - $a['order']; });

print_r($array);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/575563)

Comment: That's much easier to understand than `array_multisort()` and `array_combine()`.

Comment: This is definitely easier to understand.